# How to compute percentage using SQL(postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have a table "crime" which has 2 columns "activitydate"(timestamp without time zone) and "zipcode"(character varying(5))

eg:
table "crimes":

```
activity date               zipcode
2014-11-22 00:52:00           12345
2014-10-22 00:52:00           12345
2014-10-24 00:52:00           12345
2014-12-22 00:52:00           54321
...
```

Given a start date, end date and zip code, how to compute the percentage of zip codes that have a higher number of crimes within the given period than the current zip code?

Comment: How would you do it without SQL? Just write it down in text and than translate to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a quick and nasty way to get the count of zipcodes which have a greater count then the provided zipcode. You can then use this to get the percentage. (There is probably a more efficient way to get it though)

```
SELECT COUNT(zipcode) as numberAbove
  FROM (SELECT
            zipcode 
        FROM
            crime
        WHERE
            activitydate >= '<START DATE>'
        AND
            activitydate < '<END DATE>'
        GROUP BY
            zipcode
        HAVING
            COUNT(zipcode) > (select COUNT(zipcode) 
                               from crime 
                               where zipcode = '<ZIP CODE TO USE>'
                               and activitydate >= '<START DATE>'
                               and activitydate < '<END DATE>' )) subq;
```

sqlfiddle = http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e5f3/23